# Python Tail Recursion "Hack" using While Loop

Tags: python, recursion, tail-recursion

I've seen a few examples of getting Python to do tail call optimization by using a `while True` loop. E.g.

```
def tail_exp(base, exponent, acc=1):
    if exponent == 0:
        return acc
    return tail_exp(base, exponent - 1, acc * base)
```

becomes

```
def tail_exp_2(base, exponent, acc=1):
    while True:
        if exponent == 0:
            return acc
        exponent, acc = exponent - 1, acc * base
```

I'm curious to know if this technique is applicable to all/most recursive algorithms in Python, and if there are any downsides or "gotchas" to look out for when optimizing recursive algorithms in this way?

Comment: That's how tail call optimization is translated to imperative code in general, yes.

Comment: strictly speaking `tail_exp_2` does not use recursion... so there is no real tail call optimization.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist I would tend to agree, yet I've seen this approach touted as a way to do tail call optimization in Python. So if this is not recursion, what is it exactly, and what is its relationship to recursion?

Comment: This is neither Python-specific nor is it "tail call optimization" -- you're simply converting a recursive algorithm into an iterative one by hand, which you can always do in general. TCO is what you call it when the compiler does that conversion for you automatically, since it's fairly simple to do in the specific case of tail recursion. There are no "gotchas" involved as long as you do the conversion correctly.

Comment: It is a loop - in general recursion needs to build up a call stack in a loop that gets unwound on returns. In case of TCO, the intermediary elements of the stack don't matter and you can just overwrite the variables.

Comment: @lambda.xy.x So if you are overwriting the variables, are you in fact building up a call stack, or just recycling a single one? And if the latter, is that strictly recursion?

Comment: Going back to your original question.  While this technique works for tail recursion, it does not work in general.  In particular, it will not work when the code makes two recursive calls, such as tree algorithms.

Note, also that you did not right the simplest recursive definition of exp, but explicitly complicated it to be tail recursive.  Depending on the algorithm, this process of turning non-tail recursion into tail recursion can be easy or hard.

Comment: I'm sensing that once TCO is applied to a recursive algorithm, it is no longer technically recursive. Is that too strong a statement?

Comment: You get by with a call stack of depth one. You're basically manually doing the work of the compiler when rewriting the recursion to a loop. The instructions that the CPU executes are quite similar, because the compiler doesn't do much differently (perhaps a bit more optimizations but it's the same trick).

Comment: @Robin, related: [Python Stack Frames and Tail-Call Optimization](https://towardsdatascience.com/python-stack-frames-and-tail-call-optimization-4d0ea55b0542)

Comment: Remember that recursion technically (probably, not theoretically) is just a fancy way of using a stack data structure. Try and rewrite some of the recursion algos you have with a loop and a custom stack.

Answer (score 4):

Any recursive algorithm can be replaced by an iterative one. However, some examples will require an additional stack be added to the code, to manage state that is handled by the recursive calls in the original form. With tail recursion, there is no state to be managed, so no separate stack is needed.

Some programming languages take advantage of that fact and design their compilers to optimize out tail calls in recursive code, producing machine code that is equivalent to a loop. Python *does not do tail call optimization*, so this isn't really relevant to your question. Rewriting code by hand is not tail call optimization, it's just a particular sort of refactoring.

There are a few reasons Python chooses not to do tail call optimization. It's not because it's impossible. Python code is compiled into byte code, so at least theoretically there's an opportunity to translate a recursive call into a loop if that was desired by the developers (in practice it's a little more complicated, since Python variable names are dynamic, you can't necessarily tell if a function name refers to what you expect it to at runtime, a fact use by techniques like *monkeypatching*). However, the biggest problem with tail call optimization is that it generally overwrites useful debugging information that would usually be preserved by a call stack, like exactly how deep in the recursion you are and the exact state of those previous function calls. The Python developers have decided that they prefer the simplicity and debuggability of normal recursion over performance benefits of tail call optimization, even when the latter is possible.

If you want to rewrite an algorithm from a recursive implementation into an iterative one, you can always do so. In some cases, though, it may get a lot more complicated. Recursive implementations of some algorithms can be a lot shorter, simpler, and easier to reason about, even though iterative equivalents may be faster (and won't hit the recursion limit for large inputs). Converting tail calls into a loop is usually quite simple though. The complicated cases are generally not amenable to tail call optimization either, since they're doing complicated stuff with the values returned by their recursion.